# How to use 2 files for read variable

Tags: bash

I need help on debugging this bash script , currently the code is

```
#!/bin/bash
paste video.txt subtitles.txt | while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read -r f1 f2
do
curl -X POST https://awesomedomain/api/caption \
-d "client_id=MYID&client_secret=MYSECRET" \
-d "file_id=${f1}&captions=[{\"title\": \"ENGLISH\", \"type\": \"srt\", \"content\": \"${f2}\"}]" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
done
```

The function of this script is to automate the process of inserting subtitles on video using API (from my video provider)

> Input video.txt to ${f1}.
>
> Input subtitles.txt to ${f2}.

I've tried to search and some suggest to use paste function, and its not working.
Is there some working code so it can read 2 files and use it properly to $f1 and f2 ?

video.txt

```
ahsjy2s4s5
klisjukhj9
```

and for subtitles.txt

```
https://awesomedomain/subs/subs1.srt
https://awesomedomain/subs/subs2.srt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working"?

Comment: can't reproduce this issue with bash 4.4.23 & coreutils 8.30

Comment: It works just right in `bash 4.4-5` with `coreutils 8.26-3`

Comment: Anyway, for a more controlled environment you can use `-d` in paste to choose a delimiter, so you will know exactly what you have to put in your `IFS` var...
E.G. `paste -d '·' file1 file2 | while IFS="·" read -r f1 f2; do [...]; done`

Comment: hi @ingroxd can you explain what is while IFS="·" ? and the dot thingy

Comment: Does the `video.txt` or `subtitles.txt` contain a tab, spaces characters in them?  If yes, they will be splitted. Can you post the content of `video.txt` and `subtitles.txt`? You method is ok and should work with properly formatted strings. And `"$(printf "%\t")"` is just `$'\t'`.

Comment: You used `IFS="$(printf '\t')"` because you know that `paste` will use a tab to separate the entries... I just replaced it with `IFS='·'` and added `-d '·'` as option to `paste`, this way you are sure of what `$IFS` you are using and will avoid (for example) other line breaking for the `\t' char.

Comment: @KamilCuk i've update my post sir

Comment: @ingroxd thank you for your explanation, i get it now so i can use other than the dot , like space .

Comment: Well, your code works then, see [here](http://tpcg.io/79BJcN).  "What" is not working?

Comment: yes it work now , i tried on my other vps and its working, i believe its because of the bash version maybe . thank you all for your time to answer my question.

Comment: In order to use space as `$IFS`, you have to make sure to NOT use spaces in your files; plus, note that if you want to use space, you can omit `IFS=' '` in your `while` statement